# How to protect controls in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Using MS Excel 2003, I'd like to protect some controls I created (command buttons, comboboxes, labels, ...) to avoid users to modify them.

How can I do it? I've found only the way to protect cells, but not controls.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on the control, choose `Format Control`.
2. In the `Protection Tab`, make sure you have `Locked` checked.
3. Protect the sheet (Review Tab), make sure not to allow Edit Objects.